# I am using iText library to generate pdf in android, table is created in pdf now my concern is i dont want my cell text content in multiple lines

Tags: android, itext

[image: current output]

I don't want multiple lines text in cell content of iText library PDF file.

I have tried several solution but so far no luck

- by setting width of table to 100
- by setting column width also

  /// Note : There are total nine(9) columns
  ////  cell  text are long like Example : 0516651606515606165161

Whenever I generate a PDF in my PDF file, I get multiple line text in cell.

My expected output is I want my cell text in one single line.

Comment: Please show your current state of code and sketch the result and the desired output.

Comment: Please add additional information to the question by means of the [edit] link underneath it.

Comment: thanks for the response @mkl i have edited my question with an image